Jupyter Notebook Unable to start
When running the command jupyter notebook on CMD, I get the below error:
(data-env) C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    import prometheus_client
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\gc_collector.py", line 44, in <module>
    GC_COLLECTOR = GCCollector()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\gc_collector.py", line 15, in __init__
    registry.register(self)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\registry.py", line 40, in register
    names = self._get_names(collector)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\registry.py", line 80, in _get_names
    for metric in desc_func():
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\gc_collector.py", line 37, in collect
    collected.add_metric([generation], value=stat['collected'])
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\data-analysis\data-env\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\metrics_core.py", line 145, in add_metric
    self.samples.append(Sample(self.name + '_total', dict(zip(self._labelnames, labels)), value, timestamp))
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exemplar'

The recommendations to upgrade prometheus_client have been unsuccessful.
Below are the versions present in my laptop:
python=3.6
notebook=6.4.10
prometheus_client=0.17.0

Any assistance would be grateful.

Does this answer your question? Cannot Run Jupyter Notebook on Terminal

Unfortunately, it does not. Plus I am using windows 11

Have you checked out this post with the exact same problem and python version?
The solution was to upgrade to Python 3.7.

code shows python36-32 - so you use old Python (and it is 32bit version) and modules may not work with this version. Maybe install Python 3.12 (version 64bit) or to make sure install 3.11 because some modules may not work with the newest Python.
